# Trying to get autopep8 installed globally on VSCode, Windows WSL2

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux, autopep8

I have this package installed, but it doesn't have that green start on the top left. When I format a document, it says autopep8 is not installed and would you like to install it. I hit yes, and it says it can't find the file C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38-32/python.exe: no such file or directory.

How do I fix this. I read I need to add a path, but I don't know where or how. I'm new to VSCode and WSL2.
If I run pip3 list on my WSL2 Ubuntu 20.04 it says I have autopep8 1.5.4. But I can't format python documents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Please check if Python is available. Enter "`where python`" in the 'cmd' window:

   [image]
2. Please install and use the latest version of the [Python extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python) in VSCode extension store.
3. Please install the module "`autopep8`" in the currently selected [VSCode environment](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments).

   Check the source of the installation tool `pip`, it determines where the module is stored:

   [image]

   Check the installation package: "pip show autopep8":

   [image]

Result:

[image]

For more information about the use of Python in VSCode, you could refer to: [Python in VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial).